# Error creating new post content as described in the Quick Start guide

Tags: hugo

I have just started exploring Hugo. I have installed the latest version 0.24

As per here: https://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/

I am told to run this command:

```
hugo new post/good-to-great.md
```

however it gives this error:

```
Error: open : no such file or directory
```

I am running it from the root of the Hugo site as instructed.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the Quick Start guide out of date for this version of Hugo? Thanks.

EDIT: this is my directory structure:

```
.
├── archetypes
├── config.toml
├── content
├── data
├── layouts
├── static
└── themes
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the latest version of `hugo`

Comment: @Hackerman this is my version: Hugo Static Site Generator v0.24 darwin/amd64 BuildDate: 2017-06-21T12:53:48+01:00

Comment: For example....you first do something like `hugo new site mysite` and then you do this command `cd mysite` and then `hugo new post/testpost.md`, right?

Comment: I mean, because you need to to the `new post` command inside your site folder-directory

Comment: yup, that is exactly what i have done. I have followed the Quick Start guide exactly as written

Comment: Can you paste the content of `tree -a` to your question?

Comment: have added tree -a output to main question :)

Comment: Can you check the content folder, and check if you have a post directory in there...if not create a folder named `post`

Comment: it didn't have ./content/post so I created it...but the same error happens

Comment: Can confirm, just installed hugo on windows, the same error. It yields the error:C:\dev\git\blog\src>hugo -v new post/hello-world.md
INFO 2017/06/21 19:31:33 Using config file:
INFO 2017/06/21 19:31:33 attempting to create "post\\hello-world.md" of "post" o
f ext ".md"
Error: open : Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

Comment: Hugo 0.23 works fine.

Comment: yes, I too confirm that version 0.23 works fine on the Mac. Must be a bug in latest release..

Answer (score 1):

can resolve with 0.24 release by adding archetypes/default.md, which contains:

```
+++
title = "{{replace .TranslationBaseName "-" " " | title }}"
date = {{ .Date }}
draft = true
+++
```